# How to select a format for ad placement in facebook audience network

Tags: android, ads, facebook-ads

I just used facebook audience network for the first time and it is showing me something this after the implementation.
[image]

I have no idea what is this saying and what should I do, I tried to google it but I didn't found anything useful

Comment: i also wants to know about this answer.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution eventually ?

Comment: No, I just ignore them and everything works fine

Comment: no idea either.

Comment: any idea? anyone